# Linkedin jymbii api - don't found the jobs of my compagny

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a bug with "Jobs You Might Be Interested In Plugin Generator". The plugin doesn't found the jobs posted on my company page. I don't understand where come a bug.

The plugin run with, for example, Nestlé company, but not with my compagny.

Furthermore, I have actually 2 jobs in my page.

Can you help me?

This is the link to the plugin :
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/jymbii

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet. Please elaborate your question as its not clear what you have done till now.